# Stanford NLP - VP vs NP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have one example where Stanford NLP outputs a weird parse tree for the sentence:

```
Clean my desk
```

[image]

```
(ROOT
  (NP
    (NP (JJ Clean))
    (NP (PRP$ my) (NN desk))))
```

As you can see, it tags the word `Clean` as an adjective dependent on the verb `desk` with the whole phrase being tagged as a `Noun Phrase`, while my expectation is for `Clean` to be tagged as a verb, and the phase as a `Verb Phrase`.

The JJ-PRP$-NN combination simply doesn't make sense in English to me. Anyone ever run into something similar? I know that Stanford NLP results sometimes differ based on the sequence (?) of parsing tools run. How to make this tag properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, if you feed the sentence `"Clean my desk"` directly to the parser (actually, the 'tokenize', 'ssplit' and 'parse' tools), it gives the following result:

```
(ROOT (NP (NP (NNP Clean)) (NP (PRP$ my) (NN desk))))
```

However, now `"Clean"` is a Proper Noun - very clever, Stanford. So, if we feed the sentence in with the first word in lowercase - `"clean my desk"` - we finally get what we are looking for:

```
(ROOT (S (VP (VB clean) (NP (PRP$ my) (NN desk)))))
```

Be careful not to convert the full sentence into lowercase. While testing I've noticed the the word `"I"` turned into lowercase `"i"` is tagged as FW (Foreign Word), so only covert the first word to lowercase.

Comment: I'm trying to lowercase my sentences too. With no success. 
My Sentences: _Request approval of the document._, _View or change detailed information about the customer._, _Post the specified prepayment information._, _View or print the pro forma sales invoice._

Answer (score 1):

CoreNLP is notoriously bad at these sorts of imperative statements. This error is likely from the POS tagger mis-tagging "clean" as an adjective, although it appears the parser is also making the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I'll try and test running the parser without running the POS tagger first and see if that makes any difference.